# Is this Java code from a tutorial by Google correct in creating a variable of type Void?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

While reading Google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/connect_backend#adding_a_click_handler_for_list_greetings) on Cloud Endpoints for Android, I came across this code where they have passed a variable of type Void to a function. Is this correct? If yes, how does that work? Also, what is the point of passing variables named "unused" to functions if they are not going to be used by those functions?

```
public void onClickListGreetings(View unused) {

AsyncTask<Void, Void, HelloGreetingCollection> getAndDisplayGreeting =
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, HelloGreetingCollection> () {
            @Override
            protected HelloGreetingCollection doInBackground(Void... unused) {

                // more code
```

As always, thanks so much for helping out!! :)

Comment: The reason they pass unused arguments is because they do not want to use them. When creating an AsyncTask you have to specify the three types that the task will implement. In this case they only wanted to return HelloGreetingCollection after the task was completed. Go read up on AsyncTask if you want to understand why they used the type Void. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a variable. It's a generic argument of the [Void class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html).

Edit- As for the varargs, they're unused, so it doesn't really matter that you can't instantiate a Void.